# How can i make this loop go on for 3 tries and function correctly

Tags: c, loops, cs50

I have been learning to code for a few days and today I decided to use my limited capabilities to try to code this. I am trying to make a loop for a password input where if the password entered is correct, the loop will end. And if password is incorrect it will give you two more tries to input it correctly. I have tried writing a while loop like shown below. However, this not only did not fix the problem it also ruined the previous somewhat functional loop. Now it just accepts any input forever without giving anything back.

If you have any fixes and tips please share them!
Many thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    long password;
    int ask;
    int tries = 0;
    int keepgoing = true;
    ask = get_int("Enter Password: ");
    password = 123456789;
    while (tries < 3 && keepgoing == true);
    if (ask == password)
    {
        printf("Correct!!!\n");
        keepgoing = false;
    }
    if (ask != password)
    {
        printf("Incorrect, Try Again!!!\n");
    }
    if (tries == 3)
    {
        printf("Too many wrong attempts\n");
        keepgoing = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `;` on the while line - as it is the while block is nothing. Make it a proper block.

Comment: Also ask yourself how `tries` could ever become 3 in your code.

Comment: And add braces.  In `while(...) if() {} if () {}`, only the first `if` block is in the loop.  Use `while(...) { if() {} if() {} }` to get both `ifs` in the loop.

Comment: Nice formatting should tell you sth. Get into shape from the start.

Comment: `if (x == true)` is the same as `if (x)`, so just do the latter.

Comment: @WilliamPursell `while (...);` has nothing in the loop though.

Comment: `while (tries < 3 && keepgoing == true);`  the semicolon `;` at the end means that there is no body to this `while` loop.  (No doubt that was unintentional.)  It just keeps evaluating the condition over and over again.  Typically a while loop has a _body_ with a block surrounded by braces. e.g.: `while (tries < 3 && keepgoing == true) { /* do something here */ }` and by _do something_ I mean, minimally increment `tries` and possibly set the `keepgoing` flag to false. i.e. something that would cause the loop to exit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A little thing you forgot is "else if". By adding this, you code will loop through each of the condition as if they were a whole. Therefore, your code will stop running when a condition is met. Also, your final if statement is useless as you while loop will expire once tries = 3. Another little thing you forgot is "tries++" to increment your tries each time. Finally, you need to put your if statements inside the while loop by using curly brackets. Here is the correct code:

```c
while (tries < 3 && keepgoing == true) 
{
    if (ask == password)
    {
        printf("Correct!!!\n");
        keepgoing = false;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Incorrect, Try Again!!!\n");
        ask = get_int("Enter Password: ");
        tries++;
    }
}

if (tries == 3)
    {
        printf("Too many wrong attempts\n");
    }
```

Comment: `ask` is either `==`  to the password or not. As such you don't need an `else if`. An `else` is all you need.

Comment: What about another opportunity to enter the correct password? This goes straight to `3`.

Comment: @LeeTaylor  Yes, I forgot that. I'll change it now.

Comment: @WeatherVane It does not go straight to 3. `tries++;` only increments tries by 1.

Comment: It goes straight to 3 by repeating the loop 3 times, with no change to `ask` which you have still not corrected.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah, yes. I thought you were talking about how tries incremented. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks! I see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for so flags and extra code.

This `for()` loop will terminate when 3 tries are exhausted, or the user has entered the correct value.

```
long pswd = 123456;

for( int tries = 3; tries && get_int("Enter password") != pswd; tries-- )
    printf( "Incorrect\n" );

if( tries == 0 )
    printf( "Failed\n" );
else
    printf( "Welcome\n" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't happen to have the CS50 library and its functions installed on my system; however, the following code example should illustrate one way to approach this issue.  Following is an example of how to repeatedly prompt for a password until either the correct password is entered or the number of tries is exceeded.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    long password = 123456789;
    int ask;
    int tries = 0;

    while (1)    /* This is equivalent to "while(true)" */
    {
        // ask = get_int("Enter Password: ");   /* This statement would be used with the CS50 include and library */

        printf("Enter Password: ");             /* Equivalent to ask = get_int("Enter Password: ");*/
        scanf("%d", &ask);                      /* Equivalent to ask = get_int("Enter Password: ");*/

        if (ask == password)
        {
            printf("Correct!!!\n");
            break;                              /* Just using break to exit the "while" loop */
        }

        tries += 1;

        if (tries == 3)
        {
            printf("Too many wrong attempts\n");
            break;
        }

        printf("Incorrect, Try Again!!!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The bits to note are:

- The prompting for a password was moved inside of the while loop, so if need be, the prompt for a password is repeated.
- If either the correct password is used or the number of tries has been exceeded, a notification is printed and the "break" statement exits the "while" loop.  This simplifies using the "while" loop.

Anyway, give that a try.  Since you do have the CS50 library, you can swap out the "ask = get_int("Enter Password:" );" statement for the generic "printf" and "scanf" statements I used.

Comment: Thanks! I have a lot to learn :)